# USB ESD protection

Tags: usb, esd

I am using a microcontroller (PIC32) with a USB interface. The USB interface will be often exposed to human body ESD discharges. Should I protect against these, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB pins need protection from ESD. [Here](http://www.semtech.com/images/promo/Protecting_USB_Ports_from_ESD_Damage.pdf) is one solution using TVS devices.

Comment: The old link is dead, the new link is [here](https://www.semtech.com/uploads/documents/protecting_usb_ports_from_esd_damage.pdf). (same website)

Answer (score 1):

I have found this to be a good article that explains ESD protection: [System-Level ESD/EMI
Protection Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sszb130b/sszb130b.pdf)

Comment: The above link had moved to this one: [ESD Protection TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/sszt035/sszt035.pdf)